Mousepad not launching
I am running Xubuntu 22.04.  I have been running the text editor mousepad successfully for months, but it recently stopped working.  I uninstalled it, purged it, reinstalled, and it will not work as my regular account.  If I sudo mousepad, it launches successfully.  Ideas? TIA
